# How to use d3.js darker color method

Tags: d3.js

In [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/eYNPZPq?editors=0010) codepen I'm trying to make the orange color darker depending on the current data value. The following code works to make the bar orange. I'm using D3.js version 5.

```
entries.append("div").attr("class", "bar")
.style("width", d => barScale(d.distance) + "px")
.style("background-color", d3.color('orange'));
```

But this does not work. The below method is what the author of "Learn D3.js" uses in his book.

```
entries.append("div").attr("class", "bar")
.style("width", d => barScale(d.distance) + "px")
.style("background-color", d3.color('orange').darker(colorScale(d.distance)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a syntax error:

The second parameter of `selection.style` should be a function.

Corrected code:

```
.style("background-color", d => d3.color('orange').darker(colorScale(d.distance)))
```

Comment: Oh wow. I should of realized that when reading the code in the book. Thank you Mehdi. I should look up the books erratum.

Comment: This worked: .style("background-color", d => d3.color('orange').darker(colorScale(d.distance)));